# What is the definition of $\text{faithfully flat}$ map of rings?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

What is the definition of a *faithfully flat* map of ring ?

I know that a map of rings $A \to B$ is *flat* if it makes $B$ a flat $A$-module.

A morphism of schemes is faithfully flat if it is both surjective and flat.

So in that sense the map $A \to B$ of rings is faithfully flat if it is flat and surjective.

Is it the definition ?

Comment: Did you mean to write "if it makes $B$ a *flat* $A$-module"? In any case, a map of rings $f \colon A \to B$ is faithfully flat if $B$ is a faithfully flat $A$-module with the $A$-module structure on $B$ induced by $f$. It is a standard exercise in commutative algebra that this is equivalent to $B$ being flat as an $A$-module and the map on spectra $Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$ being surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map of rings $A\longrightarrow B$ is flat if it makes $B$ a *flat* $A$-module.

A map of rings $A\longrightarrow B$ is *faithfully flat* if it makes $B$ a *faithfully flat* $A$-module.